# SQL Server: Inserting to Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-into

I'm trying to solve a performance issue when inserting data to a linked server in SQL Server:

If I try to output a table from the first server to a table on the second server via "Insert Into" (followed by either Openquery or just 4-part name to the second server's target table), it takes upwards of 60 seconds:

```
INSERT INTO Server2.DB2.dbo.Target
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Source
```

If I execute the query ***on the second server***, telling it to read the same data from the first server and insert it into a table on the second server, it takes ~3 seconds - but the net result is the same (a table on the second server populated with the data):

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Target
SELECT * FROM Server1.DB1.dbo.Source
```

This made me think that there must be a faster way to get the data from the first server to the second, whilst still executing the code from the first server.
Is there a more efficient way to get this data between the two servers whilst still executing the stored procedure on the first server?

For wider context: 
I'm trying to optimize a bunch of stored procedures which run every day on the first server, and this issue seems to be cumulatively adding a lot of time to the daily run. The setup of the second server (out of my control) doesn't allow me to query all the tables on the first server to just run all of the procedures there instead.

Comment: afaik openquery is the fastest. Cant you use SSIS?

Comment: That's linked servers 101, really: for lots of data you always want to be writing locally and reading remotely, and not the other way around. Try setting `collation compatible` to `true` if it's not already (may or may not help). You can also invert the data flow by inserting to a local table first, then using `EXECUTE .. AT` to tell the second server to start reading data from the first one. I agree with Thomas, though, that ideally you want to move away from linked servers and towards client tooling that makes dedicated connections. It's more work, but also more maintainable.